# Does fscanf take care of \r for [^\n]?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm testing `fscanf` with following text file.

```
1 George Washington
2 John Adams
...
9 William Henry Harrison
...
46 Joseph R. Biden Jr.
```

With following `struct`,

```c
struct president_of_united_state {
    unsigned char presidency;
    char president[23]; // 9. William Henry Harrison (22)
};
```

I'm trying to understand `fscanf` with `[^\n]`.

```c
void set_presidents_of_united_states(struct president_of_united_state *const p) {
    assert(p != NULL);
    static const char FILENAME_PRESIDENTS_OF_UNITED_STATES[] = "presidents_of_united_states.txt";
    FILE *stream = fopen(FILENAME_PRESIDENTS_OF_UNITED_STATES, "r");
    if (stream == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open %s\n", FILENAME_PRESIDENTS_OF_UNITED_STATES);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PRESIDENTS_OF_UNITED_STATES; i++) {
        int const n = fscanf(stream, "%hhu %22[^\n]", &p[i].presidency, p[i].president);
        assert(n == 2);
    }
    if (fclose(stream) == EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to close the stream");
    }
}
```

### when lines are delimited with `0a`(`\n`) only,

```
3120 4765 6f72 6765 2057 6173 6869 6e67  1 George Washing
746f 6e0a 3220 4a6f 686e 2041 6461 6d73  ton.2 John Adams
```

It works as expected.

```
[7] = {char} 87 'W'
[8] = {char} 97 'a'
[9] = {char} 115 's'
[10] = {char} 104 'h'
[11] = {char} 105 'i'
[12] = {char} 110 'n'
[13] = {char} 103 'g'
[14] = {char} 116 't'
[15] = {char} 111 'o'
[16] = {char} 110 'n'
[17] = {char} 0 '\000'
```

```
[0] = {char} 74 'J'
[1] = {char} 111 'o'
[2] = {char} 104 'h'
[3] = {char} 110 'n'
[4] = {char} 32 ' '
[5] = {char} 65 'A'
[6] = {char} 100 'd'
[7] = {char} 97 'a'
[8] = {char} 109 'm'
[9] = {char} 115 's'
[10] = {char} 0 '\000'
```

### when lines are delimited with `0d`(`\r`) `0a`(`\n`)

```
3120 4765 6f72 6765 2057 6173 6869 6e67  1 George Washing
746f 6e0d 0a32 204a 6f68 6e20 4164 616d  ton..2 John Adam
```

It also works and the `char[]` filled like this.

```
[7] = {char} 87 'W'
[8] = {char} 97 'a'
[9] = {char} 115 's'
[10] = {char} 104 'h'
[11] = {char} 105 'i'
[12] = {char} 110 'n'
[13] = {char} 103 'g'
[14] = {char} 116 't'
[15] = {char} 111 'o'
[16] = {char} 110 'n'
[17] = {char} 0 '\000'
```

```
[0] = {char} 74 'J'
[1] = {char} 111 'o'
[2] = {char} 104 'h'
[3] = {char} 110 'n'
[4] = {char} 32 ' '
[5] = {char} 65 'A'
[6] = {char} 100 'd'
[7] = {char} 97 'a'
[8] = {char} 109 'm'
[9] = {char} 115 's'
[10] = {char} 0 '\000'
```

My question is that did `fscanf` ignore the `\r`?

Comment: If you can't open a file, you should say why in the error message.  `perror(FILENAME_PRESIDENTS_OF_UNITED_STATES);`

Comment: It depends on what I/s you are using.  And how the file is opened.

Comment: Don't use `assert` for error checking.  It's purpose is *not* to validate input, but to validate code logic.  Using assert to claim that the input parameter is not NULL is fine.  Using assert to make statements about the input is wrong.

Comment: A file opened in Windows text mode will convert \r\n to \n. Otherwise CR is just a char.

Comment: `fscanf` does nothing. It's the job of the C runtime to convert between the platform newline and `\n`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What is the `l/s` you mentioned? And I think I opened the file with `r` mode.

Comment: L/s is a typo for “o/s” — an abbreviation for “operating system”.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's Windows. Thanks.

Comment: @stark @phuclv So can I use just `[^\n]` regardless of platforms and actual line delimiter(s)? In this case?

Comment: While the file is a text file on Windows, yes.  On Unix, the CR in the CRLF line endings would be treated as a separate character.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: `assert` is fine to use in this context. Reading from a file with `fscanf` is not necessarily either the user interface or the security boundary. For example, a program may be reading from a pipe to a trusted partner or from a database that is expected to have a specific format. It is also fine to use in student programs where the task is to learn some new things and not to deal with making a pretty user interface.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I strongly disagree.  Even if the `fscanf` is reading from a file with a known format, system errors can occur which will impact the read.  `assert` is not appropriate here.  It is also not acceptable in a student program where it will teach bad habits.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: `assert` is acceptable in student programs where the teachers accept it and because it is simply not feasible to expect students to construct fully formed user-friendly programs right away. Learning **must** proceed incrementally; humans **cannot** learn large topics all at once. Learning always involves individual steps, training wheels, temporary assists, and other features. As for so-called “system errors,” that is fine, people may decide in some situations that “system errors” are inside their project, not outside, and `assert` is satisfactory for their purposes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Incremental learning is fine.  Teaching bad habits is not. The purpose of `assert` is not error checking.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: You have admitted there is a problem—learning must be incremental—but not given or allowed a solution. `assert` is a solution to stopping the computer from continuing when an error has occurred without burdening the student with having to write code that either they are not ready to write or that unduly burdens them at the current stage of their skill. Students can easily to taught it is acceptable to use `assert` in their assignments but that full-featured user-friendly programs need additional features.